# Docker for Mac - Hash sum mismatch

Tags: macos, ubuntu, docker

I'm using Docker for Mac with such Dockerfile (only beginning):

```
# Base image
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# Update packages list and system
RUN apt-get -y update;
RUN apt-get -y upgrade

# Allow to use add-apt-repository command
RUN apt-get -y install software-properties-common locales poppler-utils
```

and from a few days I'm getting errors like this:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/krb5/libk5crypto3_1.13.2+dfsg-5ubuntu2_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch

E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/keyutils/libkeyutils1_1.5.9-8ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch

E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/krb5/libkrb5-3_1.13.2+dfsg-5ubuntu2_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch

E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/krb5/libgssapi-krb5-2_1.13.2+dfsg-5ubuntu2_amd64.deb  Writing more data than expected (206672 > 201874) [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get -y install software-properties-common locales poppler-utils' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

Previously I was using Docker on Windows and got such errors maybe 1 or 2 times in 2 years and now on Mac I'm getting them all the time and cannot build my images.

What can be reason of this? Should I do something on my Mac or maybe change something in my Dockerfile to make it work?

Just to note, I was also playing with changes like this:

```
# Base image
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN echo 'Acquire::Acquire-by-hash "yes";' >> /etc/apt/apt.conf
RUN echo 'Acquire::CompressionTypes::Order "gz";' >> /etc/apt/apt.conf

# Update packages list and system
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y clean
RUN apt-get -y upgrade
RUN apt-get -y clean
RUN apt-get dist-upgrade

# Allow to use add-apt-repository command
RUN apt-get -y install software-properties-common locales poppler-utils
```

or

```
# Base image
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/partial
RUN echo 'Acquire::By-Hash "yes";' >> /etc/apt/apt.conf
RUN echo 'Acquire::CompressionTypes::Order:: "gz";' >> /etc/apt/apt.conf

# Update packages list and system
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apt-utils
RUN apt-get -y clean
RUN apt-get -y upgrade
RUN apt-get -y clean
RUN apt-get dist-upgrade

# Allow to use add-apt-repository command
RUN apt-get -y install software-properties-common
RUN apt-get -y install locales poppler-utils
```

but it didn't change this.

I've tested it on Windows and it is working perfectly fine. The funny thing is that when I change `FROM ubuntu:16.04` to `FROM ubuntu:17.10` on MacOS it will also work without any problems so it seemed that somehow packages are taken not from 16.04 but 17.10 when I have `FROM ubuntu:16.04`

I've already:

- restarted my Mac
- restarted Docker
- removed all data
- reset to factory defaults
- uninstalled and installed again Docker
- downgraded from mac49 to 17.12.0-ce-mac46 (21698)
- removed all images / containers and build them again

None of those change the thing. The strange is that it worked before on my MacOS (I've build images about 20-30 times before and it was fine) and also now maybe once every 100 times it would succeed now to build image but obviously this is not the best solution.

As a temporary workaround I've built all the images on Windows and pushed them to Docker hub and then pull them on MacOS but again this is only workaround and not the solution.

Comment: are you using some kind of proxy on docker host? if yes, you must setup it on Dockerfiles using ENV http_proxy="http://x.x.x.x:xxxx"

Comment: @OscarAkaElvis Thank for comment. In proxies I have set "Use system proxy" and I don't have any proxies set in my Mac

Comment: I tested one of your Dockerfiles (the last one) and it built without any problem. So there must be some kind of connection problem not related to Docker. Maybe you are not setting up a proxy because it's automatically set on the network but check if you are using a proxy, that's a common problem on Docker images building. If yes, try to evade it or build the images in an alternate network because it seems there is some kind of filtering which is smashing your plans :)

Comment: @OscarAkaElvis Could you please explain it a bit more? I'm fairly new to MacOS, but in connections I don't see any proxies set

Comment: Probably there is a proxy on your network filtering packets. Not necessarily it must be configured on computers. Probably it's integrated on router or somewhere in your network. I really think you have some kind of filter. The proof is I tested your Dockerfile and built flawlessly. Try it yourself, use other network and build it!

Comment: @OscarAkaElvis I was not able to test it in other network but again I've tested exact same Dockerfile on Windows - and there is no problem in there. Only on MacOS this problem appears.

Comment: hhmmm.... quite strange... I don't have a OSX to test. I can't figure what could be the problem, sorry :/

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek Try to delete the ubuntu:16.04 image on your Mac and then run it again to force Docker to redownload it. I'm not sure how it's possible, bo sometimes I have strange issues similar to your one and deleting Docker images usually helps. I have even created Bash alias that removes all Docker images I have: docker rmi $(docker images -q)

Comment: @MichałKalinowski Thank you for your clue but I've already deleted all the images. I also have aliases like this: `alias drmi='docker rmi $(docker images --filter "dangling=true" -q --no-trunc)'` and `alias drmia='docker rmi --force $(docker images -q)'` and I used them multiple times already

Comment: Can you delete the VM for docker and recreate a new one? Also see if this helps https://askubuntu.com/questions/751801/apt-update-fails-writing-more-data-than-expected

Comment: @TarunLalwani How can I do it? Do "reset to factory defaults" or "remove all data" I mentioned in what I've already done don't do this?

Comment: Can you try deleting `$USER/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker`? Also I added a link to previous comment, see if it helps

Comment: @TarunLalwani I've already verified link you gave me a few days ago but it didn't help. Removing the whole directory also didn't change anything - got exact same Hash sum mismatch error. The strange thing that errors usually happen for exact same packages - first one is almost always ` http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/krb5/libk5crypto3_1.13.2+dfsg-5ubuntu2_amd64.deb`

Comment: Can you do `curl -v http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/krb5/libk5crypto3_1.13.2+dfsg-5ubuntu2_amd64.deb` inside the container and see if you find anything funny?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164875/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-marcin-nabialek).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its hard to say what could be wrong here, since you have already tried a lot of things yourself. One thing I could suggest is to change the mirror. You can find the list of mirrors from

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors

Then use it like below

```
# Base image 
FROM ubuntu:16.04 

RUN sed -i '1ideb mirror.onet.pl/pub/mirrors/… xenial main' /etc/apt/sources.list 
RUN sed -i '1ideb-src mirror.onet.pl/pub/mirrors/… xenial main' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Another option you could try is to use `apt` instead of `apt-get`

```
RUN apt update && apt upgrade
RUN apt install -y software-properties-common locales poppler-utils
```

Another option you could try is using a single RUN statement

```
RUN apt update && apt upgrade && apt install -y software-properties-common locales poppler-utils
```

All this may not answer why it is happening, but it may give you a workaround

Comment: Thanks, in my case only the 1st option worked - setting mirror to one from link you have. Running everything in single command (what is by the way recommended by Docker) didn't change anything for me - the error was still there.

Answer (score 5):

My sense is you are hitting a known issue [Ubuntu bug #972077](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/972077) that I have also encountered.

Apparently, the apt repository format is subject to race conditions when a mirror is updated. This problem particularly affects repositories that change rapidly, such as a development release and align with your symptom description between 16.04 and 17.10.

The recommended solution that worked for me was to run:

```
apt-get clean
rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*
# The blog below also recommends to change your compression
apt-get update -o Acquire::CompressionTypes::Order::=gz
```

Note: This appears to be confounded by the cache you are pulling from. Thus in some cases, it appears you need to change your download repo to update your cache.

#### References:

Package Cloud Blog Post:

- https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2016/03/21/apt-hash-sum-mismatch/

Ubuntu thread on the issue:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-packages-list-due-to-a-hash-sum-mismatch-error

Unix Thread on this issue

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116641/how-do-you-fix-apt-get-update-hash-sum-mismatch/273441#273441

I hope the above helps point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunatally it doesn't work for me. As I already showed I've tried to use  `Acquire::CompressionTypes::Order::` but it didn't change anything. I was also trying to clean or remove files and each time when I was trying apt-get install I had this problem. The only thing that worked for me was setting manually other mirror as showed in second answer.

Comment: Marcin - no worries. My sense was you would likely have to change your mirror hence the update to the answer. I am just glad you got the problem sorted out. The good news is people should be able to solve the problem now.